# Why is lexical this run as another context in my lambda function?

Tags: lambda, ecmascript-6, ionic2

I've created service page that works with Google APIs to fetch data and now I want run a callback function from the page that opened the service page, though I'm having trouble elegantly handling context.

A stripped down version of my first page looks like this:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {BarPage} from '../barPage/barPage';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/foo/foo.html'
})
export class FooPage {
    static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController]];
    }

    constructor(nav) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    //...skipping code

    processData(data) {
        // do something
    }

    openFindPlacePage(event) {
        let self = this;

        this.nav.push(BarPage,
        {
            onSelect: (data) => {
                    //this.processData(data); Runs with the wrong context
                    self.processData(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my helper class is something like this:

```
import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/barPage/barPage.html'
})
export class BarPage {
    static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController], [NavParams]];
    }

    constructor(nav, navParams) {
        this.nav = nav;

        if (navParams.data.onSelect)
            this.onSelect = navParams.data.onSelect;
    }

    //...skipping code

    placeSelected() {
        // this.autocomplete was defined elsewhere
        let placeInfo = this.autocomplete.getPlace();

        if (this.onSelect)
            this.onSelect(placeInfo);

        this.nav.pop();
    }
}
```

This solution works for me as is I'm confused why I have to use *self = this* to call *processData* rather than *this* as I'd expect to be able to in a lambda function.

Comment: In which environment is this code executed?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your engine, lacking ES6 support.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm executing in a Chrome browser in a project running TypeScript on linux.

Comment: @Bergi though I'm able to get the correct context when used in places like _this.storage.get('baz').then( (data) => { //do something });_

Comment: @PhilD. Typescript compiled to ES6 or ES5? Is the transpilation result correct? Do you have the latest versions of TS and Chrome installed?

Comment: The best thing you can do is to refer to transpiled JS in both cases. When TS is transpiled to ES5, both `self` and `this` should result in identical code.

Comment: I'm transpiling to ES5 with Chrome V 52.0.2704.84 and just tried in Firefox 46.0.1. Not sure how to check TS version. I normally hate looking at transpiled JS but it was pretty straight forward. Everything looked fine when transpiled. Oddly enough the code started working this morning after restarting the PC. Though while the script works using _this_ again, chrome dev tools still report _this_ as being run by BarPage... I'm willing to close the ticket and put it down to tempremental behaviour but not sure the best way to do that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Chrome's Dev Tools still display the incorrect context for *this* in my lambda function when viewing in a source map, after a reboot the code was able to execute correctly.

This seems very odd to me but I don't know that it needs answering as the code is now executing as expected.